# Hidden input field in Angularjs not update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angularjs v1.0.7. I have a hidden form field, which it's value is related with other input value. In  http://jsfiddle.net/4ANaK/ example, hidden filed not update as I type in text input filed filed.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="action()">
      name:<input ng-model="name" type="text"  value="you name">
      <input ng-model="nice_name" type="hidden" value="Mr {{name}}" >
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = "David";

    $scope.action = function(){
        alert($scope.nice_name);                
    }
}
```

How to fixed the problem?

Comment: I don't think Angular pays attention to the value attribute like that.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Have a hidden form field be submitted that is computed from scope variables?

Comment: For some reason, I must control a hidden filed in html which is generated by server side, not in js controler code.

Comment: Alright check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Attempt 1**

Adding this to your controller solves your fiddle.  Does it solve your real problem, too?

```
$scope.$watch('name', function (value) {
    $scope.nice_name = 'Mr ' + value;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4kySW/

---

**Attempt 2**

Alright so what about this?  This is done purely in the view.

http://jsfiddle.net/4kySW/1/

```
<input ... ng-change="nice_name = 'Mr ' + name" ng-init="nice_name = 'Mr ' + name">
```

**Edit**

Looks like the `ng-init` wasn't necessary.

Comment: This is not really solve my problem, for some reason, I want to control it in html which is generated by server side, not in js controller code.